# Insert overwrite directory using Presto like Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto

In Hive, the statement below will output `foo^Bbar^Abaz`

```sql
insert overwrite directory 's3://bucket-name/foobarbaz'
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\001'
select split('foo,bar', ','), 'baz';
```

In Presto, I ran this statement:

```sql
insert overwrite directory 's3://bucket-name/foobarbaz'
select split('foo,bar', ','), 'baz';
```

With this result: `["foo","bar"]^Abaz`

What is the equivalent Presto clause for insert overwrite directory that works for arrays and structs?

It seems like Presto converted my array type into a json string, but I want this formatted to Hadoop spec with collection item and map key delimiter support.

Comment: Is your intention to INSERT 3 columns (flat), `'foo', 'bar', 'baz'`? Is the number of the columns fixed?

Comment: In this case, 2 columns should be inserted. Each record should be contain the columns: array<varchar>, varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY in the [create table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable) DDL.

```
row_format DELIMITED [FIELDS TERMINATED BY char [ESCAPED BY char]] [COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY char] ...
```

Comment: I think this would work if it applies to tables. `insert overwrite directory` doesn't have table schema metadata to pull from.

Comment: @ScottNguyen yes, you are right. It aplies to tables only.